# What is the "Votes remaining" at the bottom of the close window?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

When I click on `Close` underneath a question, at the bottom of that window, it shows a peculiar and unclear text...

[image]

The number varies, but seems to be backwards from what I expected. First of all, when voting to close a question, it takes 5 close votes to actually put it on hold. However, [a question with 1 close vote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132133/connecting-to-specific-wifi-network-using-delphi-xe5-for-android-app-development) already showed `50` here, and [a question with no close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30129289/how-to-calculate-cash-flow-using-calc-fields) had `49`.

So what does this actually mean? It's not any kind of hyperlink that I can click to see more information. When I hover it, it just says "49 votes remaining today". But what does it mean?

Comment: It would be nice if there were actually some source of explanation for what things actually mean across the entire Stack Exchange system in general.

Comment: It seems pretty clear to me. You have 49 **votes remaining**, which is specifically what the text explains. I'm not sure what part of that would be unclear or peculiar - *votes remaining* is pretty precise. *You have $5 left to spend in your account.* doesn't require an explanation from the bank.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means **you** have 49 close votes remaining to use for the day.

You get 50 total close votes to use per UTC day.